# How to capitalize a specific work when importing references from JabRef

Tags: bibliographies

I am using JabRef to import references in LyX for my thesis. I am using IEEE style for bibliography. Using this style I get somewhat this type of results

> "A. J. Navas, A. G. Zambrana, and A. Notario, "Efficient lognormal channel model for turbulent fso communications," Electronics Letters, vol. 43, no. 3, pp. 178 - 179, 2007.

However, i want the word "FSO" to be capitalized instead of "fso". Is there any command for this. Please help me.

Answer (score 10):

I do not know whether I understood your question properly. You are typing fso in caps but you are getting them in small letters? IF so, this is the answer. Generally bibTeX will not care for capital letters in the middle of a title. Even if you type them in capital letters, they will be converted in to small letters. You have to tell bibtex to leave those capitals alone by enclosing them inside braces like `{FSO}`

```
@ARTICLE{Navas,
  author = {A. J. Navas and A. G. Zambrana and A. Notario},
  title = {Efficient lognormal channel model for turbulent {FSO} communications},
  journal = {Electronics Letters},
  year = {2007},
  volume = {43},
  pages = {178--179},
  number = {3},
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If bibTeX should respect capitalisation for the whole title you can also put the whole title in brackets.

```
@ARTICLE{Navas,
author = {A. J. Navas and A. G. Zambrana and A. Notario},
title = {{Efficient lognormal channel model for turbulent FSO communications}},
journal = {Electronics Letters},
year = {2007},
volume = {43},
pages = {178--179},
number = {3},
}
```